# reinforce section of 6x12 header

Tags: structural-engineering

I need to remove 5" x 48" of the middle of a 6"x12"x16' header so I can clear the AC units on the top of my motorhome entering the carport. The header supports a 6/12 pitch roof with trusses.  What method of reinforcing should be accomplished.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please post some pictures?

Answer (score 3):

you need to hire an engineer and pull a permit.

The rough first idea is either to install posts under the header, or double it by attaching another identical on top of it.

Both require attention to fasteners and connectors.

Comment: We don't know what country the OP is in, so we have no idea if he needs a "permit" or anything signed off by an "engineer". But anyone here who *is* able to give professional-quality advice is unlikely to do so without a lot more information (which almost certainly includes actually *looking* at the current structure to see what state it is in)

Comment: @alephzero, agreed. But sometimes just to have rough idea early on of what are the option is helpful when thinking about a project. My point was to emphasize the OP's idea will render the header useless beyond any hope of reinforcement.